# Python 3.6 - Find a string inside a nested Dict

Tags: python-3.x

In the following list of `volume` dictionaries:

```
[
 {'AvailabilityZone':'ap-southeast-2b'},
 {'AvailabilityZone':'ap-southeast-2b', 'Tags':[{'Key': 'Name'},{'Key': 'Project1'}]},
 {'AvailabilityZone':'ap-southeast-2b', 'Tags':[{'Key': 'Name'},{'Key': 'Project2'}]}
]
```

I need to find every volume that has the `Project1` key tag.

I tried doing the following:

```
found_volumes = []

for one_volume in volumes:
    if ('Tags' in one_volume) and ('Key' in one_volume['Tags'] == 'Project1'):
        found_volumes.append(one_volume)
```

But it is not working, I get 0 items in `found_volumes` at the end.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The chained comparison seems... obscure.

Comment: Well, it's certainly not you want. Let me find a dupe.

Comment: Can't find it. Anyway your condition `('Key' in one_volume['Tags'] == 'Project1')` is equivalent to `('Key' in one_volume['Tags']) and (one_volume['Tags'] == 'Project1')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you missed the fact that `Tags` is a list.

```
found_volumes = []

for one_volume in volumes:
    if ('Tags' in one_volume):
        for one_tag in one_volume['Tags']:
            if 'Key' in one_tag and one_tag['Key'] == 'Project1':
                found_volumes.append(one_volume)
                break
```

As a side note, testing for key existence isn't quite Pythonic. I would write the code like this:

```
found_volumes = []

for one_volume in volumes:
    for one_tag in one_volume.get('Tags', []):
        if one_tag.get('Key', None) == 'Project1':
            found_volumes.append(one_volume)
            break
```

Comment: "testing for key existence isn't quite Pythonic". Not true. Just doing it the hard way isn't Pythonic. Remove the try-catch and do `one_tag.get('Key') == 'Project1` for a key check that saves you three lines and an unnecessary indent.

Comment: @MadPhysicist In case `one_volume` does not contain `'Tags'`, the `try-except` is still useful :)

Comment: `get` will return `None` in that case and the comparison will be `False`, as you'd want it to be.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I mean, the first item in `volume` does not contain `'Tags'`, it can be caught by the `except` clause.

Comment: oh I see: `for one_tag in one_volume.get('Tags', [])`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the obligatory one-liner:

```
found_volumes = [vol for vol in volumes if any(v.get('Key') == 'Project1' for v in vol.get('Tags', []))]
```

Comment: Thank you! that did it, but while you're good at it, I need one more thing, is there a one-liner to find all volumes that do NOT have a certain tag? simply changing == with != won't do it because a volume can have multiple tags.

Comment: @RonaDona. Add not before any.and remove the empty curly braces in the default value of the tags get.

Comment: This is really not better than iBug's answer. You should really select his.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the second nested dictionary is in fact in a list and you are not iterating over it right. You are comparing the list pointer (sort of with 'Key')
Here is an alternative of how you should do it:

```
volumes = [ {'AvailabilityZone':'ap-southeast-2b'}, {'AvailabilityZone':'ap-southeast-2b', 'Tags':[{'Key': 'Name'},{'Key': 'Project1'}]},
            {'AvailabilityZone':'ap-southeast-2b', 'Tags':[{'Key': 'Name'},{'Key': 'Project2'}]}
            ]

found_volumes = []

for one_volume in volumes:
    if ('Tags' in one_volume): 
        for dict in one_volume['Tags']:
            if ('Key' in dict and dict['Key'] == 'Project1'):
                found_volumes.append(one_volume)
print(found_volumes)
```

As you can see `one_volume['Tags']` is a list of dictionaries. You loop through each dictionary and check for the key-value match.

Comment: You will crash with a `KeyError`.

Comment: Nevemind, I see what you mean. I have changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

by example:

```
def find_volume(volumes, tag):
    return [item for item in volumes if len([True for tag in item.get('Tags', []) if tag.get('Key') == tag]) > 0]
```

and use:

```
find_volume(volumes, 'Project2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to solve the problem:

```
volumes=[
     {'AvailabilityZone':'ap-southeast-2b'},
     {'AvailabilityZone':'ap-southeast-2b', 'Tags':[{'Key': 'Name'},{'Key': 'Project1'}]},
     {'AvailabilityZone':'ap-southeast-2b', 'Tags':[{'Key': 'Name'},{'Key': 'Project2'}]}
    ]

found_volumes = [i for i in volumes if any (j.get('Key')=='Project1' for j in i.get('Tags',[]))]
print(found_volumes)
```

The Output that you will get on executing the above code would be:

```
>>> [{'AvailabilityZone': 'ap-southeast-2b', 'Tags': [{'Key': 'Name'}, {'Key': 'Project1'}]}]
```